# Code to create an individual in an ontology?

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

I want to insert data in my ontology using this code:

```
Resource resource = model.createResource(X_NAMESPACE + Global_ID);
Property prop = model.createProperty(RDF_NAMESPACE + "type");
Resource obj = model.createResource(X_NAMESPACE + "X");
model.add(resource, prop, obj);
```

First, does this code correctly create an individual of the specified type?
When I run this code, it saves without a problem, and the model looks correct, but when I want to query the model, I had problems.  For example, I save some data in X, and when I retrieve it, all other data is retrieved.

Comment: We can't make any guess about what your query should or shouldn't return if you don't show us your query.  What's your query?  What results do you get?  What results did you expect?  Please edit the question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for creating a resource is correct, but it's not very idiomatic.  There are methods provided by the [Model](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) interface that will make creating resources easier, and there are methods in the [Resource](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html) interface that will make adding types easier too.  Heres' code that illustrates these:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;

public class CreateResourceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        String NS = "http://stackoverflow.com/q/22471651/1281433/";
        model.setNsPrefix( "", NS );

        // Create the class resource
        Resource thing = model.createResource( NS+"ThingA" );

        // The model API provides methods for creating resources
        // of specified types.
        Resource x = model.createResource( NS+"X", thing );

        // If you want to create the triples manually, you can 
        // use the predefined vocabulary classes.
        Resource y = model.createResource( NS+"Y" );
        model.add( y, RDF.type, thing );

        // You can also use the Resource API to add properties
        Resource z = model.createResource( NS+"Z" );
        z.addProperty( RDF.type, thing );

        // Show the model
        model.write( System.out, "TTL" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Joshua, thanks alot for your revision , you are very understanding people

Comment: @user2532099 No problem;  if you provide more information about your query (as asked in a comment on the question), we might be able to resolve that issue, too.